# Edit symmetrically encrypted file with gpg

Tags: script, gnupg

I am writing a script that lets the user edit a gpg encrypted file with vim. I have already done it with asymmetric encryption like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# TODO: add support for symmetric encryption

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Needs two arguments, exiting"
    exit
else
    file="$1"
fi

if [ -z "$EDITOR" ]; then
    editor="vim"
else
    editor=$EDITOR
fi

tmp_file="$(mktemp)"

gpg -d --yes -o "$tmp_file" "$file"

gpg_exit=$?

if [ $gpg_exit -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Decryption failed, exiting"
    rm $tmp_file
    exit
fi

original_mod_time=$(stat -c %Y "$tmp_file")

$editor "$tmp_file"

new_mod_time=$(stat -c %Y "$tmp_file")

if [ "$original_mod_time" -ne "$new_mod_time" ]; then
    gpg -o "$file" -e --yes -r recipient "$tmp_file"

    gpg_exit=$?

    if [ $gpg_exit -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Encryption failed, exiting"
    fi
fi

shred -u "$tmp_file"
```

However, when I want to make a script that supports symmetric encryption, I don't want to have the user type the password in twice, because it can lead to mistyping and it is annoying. Because of this I have to store the password somehow. I can `read passphrase`, but running `gpg --passphrase $passphrase` is not secure, because any process can read commandline arguments. Is there any other way to do this? I don't want to store the passphrase in a file.

Also, is there any way to make a script like this without ANY file creation (no temporary files)? That would be more secure. Something like this would be nice:
`gpg -d $file | vim --some-option | gpg -c -o $file`

Answer (score 0):

There are vim plugins for this, like `vim‑gnupg`: [Plugin for transparent editing of gpg encrypted files.](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645)

---

There's not many options for hiding secrets from commandline args. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065618/7411885) are all the valid ones, and they generally require reading from stdin. My preferred one is a temporary file descriptor:

```sh
read -s secret
cat <( s=$secret printenv s )
# cmdline only shows pseudo-file path like  
cat /dev/fd/67
```

---

Vim can read from stdin if you add `-` like `gpg -d $file | vim -`.

You can write vim's output to another command using `:w !gpg -c -o $file` from within vim (not useful for something other people will use), but you can not use vim in pipeline without some awkward stream manipulation like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686895/7411885. You could also use `vipe` from [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/) which does output to pipeline.

You can disable vim's temp files in the `.vimrc` config:

```
set nobackup       "no backup files
set nowritebackup  "only in case you don't want a backup file while editing
set noswapfile     "no swap files
```